Expand svg text spans to full page width
Following the solution made by markE, for the question Split text into pages question. I want to use drawSVG. I have tried to extend the span to the full width of the page using dx to create svg spans but the text gets cutoff.
Altering the answer in the jsfiddle to a bigger pageWidth, can I use dx or do I have to calculate the x in order to place more text spans across the page?
function drawSvg(lines,x){
    var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    var sText = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
    sText.setAttributeNS(null, 'font-family', 'verdana');
    sText.setAttributeNS(null, 'font-size', "14px");
    sText.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', '#000000');
    for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
        var sTSpan = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'tspan');
        sTSpan.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', x);
        sTSpan.setAttributeNS(null, 'dy', lineHeight+"px");
        sTSpan.appendChild(document.createTextNode(lines[i].text));
        sText.appendChild(sTSpan);
    }
    svg.appendChild(sText);
    $page.append(svg);
}

Attempted the jsfiddle included in markE answer. The text gets cutoff when I try to expand the pageWidth.

The text is cropped as there is no width specified for the svg - resulting in the default 300px width. Since svg has no line-breaks - you can't just expand lines. The above concept splits text into lines according to a max page/layout width. Frankly, svg text has more limitations than benefits - are you sure you can't use HTML/CSS? You may also test the html-to-svg conversion in this post 'Accessing displayed hyphens of an HTML element with JavaScript'
